# How to find the first and last of one of several characters in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string

So I have a list of strings such as this:

```
my_list=["---abcdefgh----abc--","--abcd-a--","----------abcdefghij----ab-","-abcdef---a-","----abcdefghijklm----abc--"]
```

I want, for each string, to retrieve the position where the first and last letters appear. Or in other words, to find the position of the first character that isn't a "-" and the position of the last character that isn't a "-". It would be perfect if I could save the result as two lists, one of the first positions and another for the last.

I've tried using find() at least for the first position but since the character I'm trying to find is one of several letters, I don't know how to do it.

The output I wanted was something like this:

```
first_positions=[3,2,10,1,4]
last_positions=[17,7,25,11,23]
```

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: Voted to close because no reproducible example provided.

Comment: I added the output I was looking for, I din't know if there's anything else I should add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation without using regex.

```
my_list=["---abcdefgh----abc--","--abcd-a--","----------abcdefghij----ab-","-abcdef---a-","----abcdefghijklm----abc--"]


def find_i(word):
    first = None
    last = None
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if first == None:
            if letter != '-':
                first = i       
        else:
            if letter != '-':
                last = i
    return (first, last)


r = list(map(find_i, my_list))
print(r) #I like this output more, but it is up to you.


first_positions = [i[0] for i in r]
last_positions = [i[1] for i in r]

print(first_positions)
print(last_positions)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 17), (2, 7), (10, 25), (1, 10), (4, 23)]
[3, 2, 10, 1, 4]
[17, 7, 25, 10, 23]
```

Comment: yes that's perfect, but I used a bad reproducible example. I new updated it for a better one, because my strings sometimes have "-"s in between the letters, and I wanted to account for that. I wrote a new output, thanks for you answer

Comment: @tadeufontes Fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly a nicer way to do this, but one way to get it is to match all non-hyphen characters and get the start index of that match, and then to match all non-hyphen characters which are followed by 0 or more hyphens and then the end of the line, and get the start index of that match, and compile them into li

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.search(r'[^-]+', string).start() for string in my_list]
[3, 2, 10, 1, 4]
>>> [re.search(r'[^-]-*$', string).start() for string in my_list]
[17, 7, 25, 10, 23]
```

Comment: yes that's perfect, but I used a bad reproducible example. I new updated it for a better one, because my strings sometimes have "-"s in between the letters, and I wanted to account for that. I wrote a new output, thanks for you answer

Comment: @tadeufontes Ive updated mine as well, if you are interested in the regular expression approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Check string is alphabet or not and then add index of string in the list. if you want to find first positions then by default function takes first then it returns the first indexes of string else it returns the last indexes

```
my_list=["---abcdefgh----abc--","--abcd-a--","----------abcdefghij----ab-","-abcdef---a-","----abcdefghijklm----abc--"]
def get_index(string,find='first'):
  index_lt=[]
  for idx,char in enumerate(string):
    if char.isalpha():
      index_lt.append(idx)
  return index_lt[0] if find=='first' else index_lt[-1]

print([get_index(string) for string in my_list])
#[3, 2, 10, 1, 4]
print([get_index(string,find='last') for string in my_list])
#[17, 7, 25, 10, 23]
```